# How much lift does the wing attach fitting actually carry?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, lift, ultralight, aircraft-structures

How do I calculate the lift force that the the bolt that join the wings to the fuselage of a strutted or braced airplane carry?

I know in a cantilever airplane,the bolts have to carry all of the lift load on a wing but how about a strutted airplane - how do the wing attach bolts share the lift with the wing braces or struts, i.e. is the lift load shared between them, the bolts carrying half and the bracing wires or struts carrying the other half?

Comment: The wings carry themselves, any engines attached to them and the fuel inside. Only the remaining load e.g. the weight of the fuselage is carried through the connection of the fuselage and wing.

Comment: This only applies to aircraft with conventional spar designs. Some aircraft, like the homebuilt BD-5, have a spar that slides over a center carry-through spar and uses a small taper bolt to prevent movement in torsion. Works well as long you remember to inspect the hardware on a regular basis.

Comment: On an aircraft with flexible wire-based wings and significant washout, I've seen the lower wires go completely slack during high-speed flight, due to the torque generated by the downlifting wingtips during high-speed flight.  Food for thought when formulating the answers--

Comment: Instead of the lift loads being carried by the bolts you might consider bolted flanges.  You basicly make this part stronger than the wing and spar, not weaker.  Like Peter K said, it is also important to know the strength properties of the components of the structure. Find the weakest point.  That is where improvement is possible, provided weight increase is not too extreme.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the elastic deformation of wing and strut. Extreme example: Make the strut a rubber band and all lift needs to be carried by the wing and its fittings. Other extreme: Make the wing spar (or attachment points - this works either way) from rubber - now the strut needs to take all the loads.

In real life, stiffness attracts tension and compression, and in order to know the load distribution between wing spar and strut you need to look at them with a slight deformation from loading. How much resistance does each show (in isolation) against that deformation? This will tell you in what ratio the forces will split between wing and strut. Make sure to use the [stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness) of the real structure - the material property called [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) is not what I mean here.

If you want to be safe, you need to consider any single point failure and still have a flyable airplane. Normally, you design your structure with a safety factor (usually 1.5, but higher for fittings). Now assume that in turn each of the structural members is missing and calculate the loads on the remaining structure with a safety factor of 1.0. Dimension each part at least for those loads and you should be pretty sure that the intact structure will work out fine.

Comment: Anonymous down voter: If you don't understand structural mechanics please ask in the comments or your own question. Sprinkling downvotes on answers you don't understand isn't helping anybody.

Comment: Deformation is caused by the forces acting on the structural members. Determine forces first, then deformation follows from the material properties. I wasn't the downvoted, by the way.

Comment: @Koyovis And I didn't downvote your answer, either. The deformation is to determine stiffness of the part. The ratio in stiffness is inverse to the ratio of the forces in an overdetermined structure. The forces first approach only works if there are enough degrees of freedom (Cremona plan etc.).

Comment: The diagonal strut transforms the inner wing construction to a kinematically and statically determined system, with the triangle experiencing compression and tension forces. Within the triangle, both upper and lower skin experience stress in the same direction (tension or compression). Only outside the strut is the wing still a cantilever beam, with upper skin under compression and lower skin under tension. Point is: adding the strut does not create a statically overdetermined structure, which your answer addresses.

Comment: @Koyovis: Depends entirely on the wing root mount. If that is a hinge, you are correct. If it has a central spar running all the span (which is how it is mostly done), it is indeed an overdetermined structure.

Comment: It will have one or more spars, yes. Triangles are statically determined if the connection points can be modelled as not absorbing much torque (which they should be). The central bit of the wing and the two struts form a triangle,  mainly being loaded with forces inline of the beams. Only thing is to prevent the upper skin from popping off from the pressure differential.

Answer (score 2):

In flight, the fuselage hangs off of the wing. For dimensioning purposes, consider:

- the intersection points to exert no moments and to behave as hinges;
- weight W of the fuselage to be concentrated in the Centre of Gravity;
- lift of each wing to be concentrated in its Centre of Lift.

[image]

If we dimension the construction in this way, we over-dimension which is never a bad idea with primary construction bolts. In reality the following factors alleviate the loads:

- The bolts are modelled as hinges which cannot exert a moment, but actually they do exert torque.
- The wing lift is distributed loading, with most of it near the wing root.

Bolts 1, 2 and 3 experience lift and gravity forces from the construction, and exert equal and opposite forces in order for everything to stay in one piece. Fuselage weight is transferred to bar 2-3 which distributes the load evenly over bolts 2 and 3. Remove the bolts and the fuselage falls from the assembly.

Force equilibrium in point 1 from [this answer:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Um2.png)

- $F_{13} \cdot sinψ = ½L => F_{13} = \frac{L}{2sinψ}$
- $F_{12} = F_{13} \cdot cosψ = \frac{L}{2tanψ}$

In point 2, bolt reaction force in green:

[image]
* $F_{V} = ¼W$ $\tag{Vertical}$
* $F_{H} = \frac{L}{2tanψ}$ $\tag{Horizontal}$

In point 3, bolt reaction force in green:

[image] 
* $F_{V} = ¼W - F_{13} \cdot sinψ =  ¼W - ½L$ $\tag{Vertical}$
* $F_{H} = \frac{L}{2tanψ}$ $\tag{Horizontal}$

Comment: The forces on the strut are not in equilibrium

Comment: @Gypaets Strut 2 - 3 can be removed, all forces to be absorbed by the bolt supports.

Comment: I mean the vertical forces on strut 1-3. Vertical reaction force on the upper hinge (2) should also be 0.

Comment: This appears to ignore that a portion of created lift must lifts the wing itself, not the fuselage.

Comment: @JWalters Yes it's over-dimensioned. Also, lift does not concentrate in one point but is distributed over the wing.

Comment: @Gypaets the forces are held in equilibrium by the bolts. These are the forces acting on the bolts.

Comment: +1 just for the picture.  Try making a bookshelf without the "strut".  Shown here is the positive G case.  The bolts 1 and 3 would have to be torn from their mountings.

Comment: @Koyovis Ok... I guess I am beginning to understand what you did. The maths are ok then, but the assumption that the $W/4$ forces are acting on the bolts as a separate force is wrong: if you restrain the system at the bolts 2-3 only the forces on the wing side should be considered. Think what would happen if you change the support and assume the c.g. of the aircraft to be clamped: the bolts would only carry the loads of the wing. Forces shouldn't depend on where you support the structure, should they?

Comment: @Gypaets Forces depend very much on where you support the structure. On ground, the fuselage is supporting the wing. In the air, the wing supports the fuselage.

Comment: @Koyovis Different load situations require different supports, that's for sure. However, if you look at a single load case, the structure is in equilibrium. The reaction forces at the bolts don't depend on where we put our imaginary support- in stationary flight you could put it anywhere. Assuming a fixed support at the cg should lead to the same section forces at a section 1cm from the wingtip as if we would assume the aircraft to be clamped at the wingtip. To calculate to forces the bolts are seeing you have to do an imaginary cut and take either the forces left or right of it, but not both.

Comment: @Gypaets I’ve put the supports in stationary flight underneath bolt 1 and its counterpart on the right wing.

Comment: @Koyovis Then the error in the calculation is how the vertical force is split between joints 2 and 3. We can assume that the weight is splitted 1/4---1/4, but it could also be splitted differently: e.g. 1/2---0 or 1/8---3/8. The only solution consistent with the assumption of a free rotation joints at 2 and 3 is $F_{V2}=0$ and $F_{V3}=L/2$ (since its stationary flight let's simplify W=L).

Comment: #Gypaets Fuselage weight is transferred to bar 2-3 which distributes the load evenly over bolts 2 and 3. Remove the bolts and the fuselage falls from the assembly. The bolts are modelled as hinges to make sure that the construction is kinematically determined. The construction is not only dimensions for stationary flight, that is why L and W remain separate in my drawing.

Comment: @Koyovis If you have a pin joint at 2 no vertical force will go through it, joint 3 will carry it all. I guess it is difficult to explain in comments, but try to draw the whole mechanical system with all supports, joints and forces involved, perhaps you'll see it better.

Comment: @Gypaets feel free to use your knowledge to provide an answer with a drawing.