# What is the function of interplane strut of a Biplane?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, aircraft-structures, biplane

What kind of load does the interplane strut(s) carry,is it compression, tension or shear?
In order words,what's their function and how do you calculate the force that the interplane strut carries?[image]

Comment: As Koyovis's answer shows, you simply have to calculate the vertical lift load acting at the interplane connection point to the lower wing panel to determine the compression load on the interplane strut, which will be somewhere around half or a bit more or less of the panel's total lifting force depending on the spanwise location.

Comment: Could you crop that image so it doesn't waste so much space above and below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wing strut prevents the lower wing from bending upwards due to the lift forces.

[image]

The biplane is a truss structure: rectangular shapes are "crossed out" by diagonal structural members, in order to create triangular shapes with only tension and compression in their structural members, no bending. If the diagonal is a rod, it can transfer both compression and tension forces and only one diagonal is required. If it is a cable, it can only transfer tension forces, and the other diagonal needs to be crossed out by a cable as well.

In flight, lift wants to bend the wings upward and lengthen the diagonal, which becomes tension loaded. The upper wing is then prevented from bending upwards and becomes compression loaded.

The interplane strut connects the lower wing with the upper wing, and prevents the lower wing from bending upwards. It is compression loaded: the diagonal exerts a downward force, lower wing lift exerts an upward force.

The method of how to compute the force is in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65549/21091). In a truss structure the intersection points are modelled as hinges, and the structure members are dimensioned to carry the resulting tension/compression loads.

Comment: Minor quibble, but on biplanes with wire bracing it's a pin joint structure so the dotted lines should really be straight.  The curve implies root fittings able to take bending, like on a Fokker DR-1.

Comment: @JohnK the dotted lines are what the wings would do if there was no diagonal structural member.

Comment: the root fittings on biplanes are pin joints that can't take any bending.  If you took out the diagonal member, it would fold up like a parallelogram.

Comment: @JohnK I know. It's a truss structure.

Comment: Read my first comment carefully.

Comment: I think @JohnK is saying that if the diagonal member weren't there, the structure would bend at the joints, not by bending the wings. The shape would still be a parallelogram, just one with no horizontal edges. I don't think that's quite true though: the biplanes I know with wire bracing have each wing as a single member end-to-end, not separate left and right wings. Although the pin joints at the wires are (fairly) free to rotate, the wing roots are rigid, so the wings would still bend before the structure crumples.

Comment: @Dan Hulme Yes that is the case, for the top wing, if a biplane has a one piece wing so it's a beam from tip to tip. However that's not very common and most biplanes have a separate center section and single bolt joints from center section to upper wing panel, and fuselage to lower wing panel.  They are true pin jointed parallelograms. The Fokker DR-1 Triplane did have cantilever spars for all three wings however, and the spar roots were in pure bending, _because they didn't have flying wires at all_, and the interplane struts were only there because the German Air Ministry insisted on them.

Comment: This feels like a good reminder that wing structures are complex with many different fine details in various design options. - Vertical struts may at times carry a dynamic load as the end of a box-beam structure in some cases, transferring both compression and tension loads. [Wing loading can get complex, especially if a structure is approaching a 'rapid unplanned disassembly' state due to 'unfavourable conditions']

Comment: @DanHulme Indeed, that is how box beam structures are modelled,, with the intersection points absorbing zero torque and therefore acting as hinges.

Answer (score 4):

It carries compression. The compression force is the share of the lower panel's lift being borne by the interplane strut's connection to the lower wing.  So to calculate the compression load for, say 1G flight at gross weight, you simply need to determine the lift force present at the interplane strut's attachment based on the wing panel's loading and the attachment's location in the lift distribution of the panel.  It's going to be somewhere in the range of half of the total lift being produced by the lower panel.

The ONLY member in significant tension in this structure is the flying wire (the red shows what happens if the flying wire breaks), and in most biplanes with center sections and single bolt jointed structures at the fuselage attachments there are no bending loads at all, except airloads pushing up on the spar beam along its length.

[image]